# MS Excel VBO option missing in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

I am trying to learn Blue Prism in order to complete a proof of concept.

I added an action for the purpose of reading an MS Excel. As I understand, first I need to add a "Create Instance" action, but in the drop down the "MS Excel VBO" option itself is missing. The "help" page indicates the VBO may not be properly installed. What to do now? [image]

Answer (score 9):

You have to import the VBO itself first. Once logged into Blue Prism, choose `File > Import...`:

[image: Blue Prism File Menu]

From the resulting dialog, browse to the `VBO` folder within the directory in which Blue Prism was installed and open the file called `BPA Object - MS Excel.xml`. In most cases, the directory in question should be located at a path similar to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate\VBO`.

After you've successfully imported the object, close and re-open whatever processes/objects you have open to see the MS Excel VBO option in your Action Stage configuration:

[image: Blue Prism action stage configuration with MS Excel VBO in object list]

Comment: Perfect answer :-) I was able to successfully import the xml and fixed the issue. Thanks a lot !